# Fullcalendar inside an accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to put a Fullcalendar inside a collapsible accordion. For some reason when I open the accordion it only displays the top of the calendar and does not show the entire object. Is there sometime simple I'm  missing?

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    //Load Full Calendar
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
      },

      editable: true,
      events: [
        {
          title: 'All Day Event',
          start: new Date(y, m, 1)
        },
      {
          title: 'Click for Google',
          start: new Date(y, m, 28),
          end: new Date(y, m, 29),
          url: 'http://google.com/'

        }
      ]
    });
//Accordion
   $(".btn").on( "click", function() {
        $("#toggleDemo").collapse('toggle');
    });

  });
```

html

```
  <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-10">
             <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggleDemo" value="Calendar">

<!-- Collapsible Element HTML -->
<div id="toggleDemo" class="collapse collapse">
  <h1>In Here</h1>
    <div id="calendar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: is the accordion collapsed when the calendar is initialised? If so, it may not create the calendar correctly on a hidden element. You might have to wait to initialise the calendar until the accordion section is opened, or at least call the fullCalendar "render" method (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/render) to force it to re-draw itself whenever the accordion section which contains it is opened. Try that and see if it helps.

Comment: Yes, the accordion starts off collapsed. I see the problem, the calendar needs to be rendered first so I'll try and figure out how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: Try the "render" method first as I mentioned, this will force fullCalendar to draw (or re-draw) the calendar without completely re-initialising it (and thus losing any changes of state)

Comment: Yes, I've been trying to get  $('#calendar').fullCalendar( ‘render’ ); to work but think I might be using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working demo: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/zaZjYN

It shows fullcalender with accordian. There was just an issue of moment js version. include this version file

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js
```

It will work!!

Comment: did you change something from OP's code in order to make it work? If so please clarify, as it's not obvious in the large-ish amount of code involved in this.

Comment: No, I have just changed version of moment js. try suggested version, it will work!

Comment: I did, and it does. Useful to clarify for everyone that instead of just a code dump - thanks for editing. But...how do you know it's the momentJS that's the issue? OP didn't include any script references in the question...

Comment: I was using moment.js version 2.1.0. It now works with version 2.9.0 but I had to use more recent version of fullcalendar too.

Comment: you can use composer or npm for managing latest version of all third party libraries

Comment: Any idea why the calendar end up being squashed within the accordion? Bootstrap seems to be distorting it.

Comment: because of class you set so it will be listed within the area. do you want it in fullscreen?